# NASM Assembler Debugger

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Is there a utility like CodeView that I can use to step through code assembled by **NASM** where I can see the current state of the registers/memory?

Comment: The question should be phrased thus: how do I make NASM emit debugger info?

Pretty much every single modern debugger (Visual Studio, Eclipse, Xcode, gdb) allows for assembly-level tracing and register/memory inspection. The trick is to make your program debugger-friendly.

Comment: I was able to setup Visual Studio to step through the assembly. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: See the bottom of [the x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for some asm debugging tips for GDB like `layout reg`, mentions of some GUI front-ends for GDB, and for Visual Studio asm debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to compile assembly code with gas, and link it with ld, and then use **gdb** to debug it.
I don't know if it's applicable to you, but it should.

Comment: asm GDB tips at the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info

Answer (score 3):

ok, gdb is fine. But if you are interested in graphical software, I
recommend you to use SASM (SimpleASM). It is like an IDE for the most popular assembly languages. So, look at [here](http://dman95.github.io/SASM/english.html)